# Check what language the user is currently viewing my DotNetNuke webpage in?

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

How would I be able to check what language the user is currently viewing my DotNetNuke webpage in?

If I'm only giving the options of english (canadian) and french (canadian), how would I check?

I've tried looking into CurrentCulture, but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to do it :-)  hope this helps someone out

Imports System.Threading

Dim english As New CultureInfo("en-CA")
Dim french As New CultureInfo("fr-CA")

If Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Equals(french) Then
....
else
....
end if

Answer (score 2):

in C# you can use this "(Page as DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase).PageCulture.Name" to get the current locale.